# Memory leak with Mongo Java Connection

Tags: java, mongodb, memory-leaks

I am constructing MongoClient Connection in the below manner :

```
public static synchronized MongoClient getInstance(String mongoDbUri) {
        try {
            // Standard URI format: mongodb://[dbuser:dbpassword@]host:port/dbname
            if( mongoClient == null ){
                mongoClient = new MongoClient(
                              new MongoClientURI(mongoDbUri));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(
                    "Error mongo connection : ",
                    e.getCause());
        }
        return mongoClient;
    }
```

Over a period of time when multiple transaction is run I am seeing some memory eat up with the application which is not getting released.

When analysed the heap dump saw that there was memory consumption was maximum with the class

`com.mongodb.internal.connection.PowerOfTwoBufferPool`

The mongo client is trying to connect to a mongos instance.The application has 3 replica sets on 3 shards and one config server to hold the metadata.

To add more details to the same , I have a spring managed bean annotated with **@Component**.There is an annotation with **@PostConstruct** for the bean in which the above method is called.In the spring class we are doing `insert/update/create` using the Mongo Client.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show more context for that connection creation code.

Comment: As @RobertMoskal has basically stated, this "small snippet" is by no means enough information to diagnose a "Memory Leak". I would aslo suggest that it is not a "leak" at all. But in fact you are calling your "instance" over and over again when it should be a single dependency call.

Comment: @user3561036: added more details ,let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: It's better, but "where and when are you calling this" and "is this a singleton" rather than an instance being called over and over. Some things such as "SpringData" provide a "service" mechanism that does this. Otherwise you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: @user3561036: Yes this is singleton in nature.This is called over and over by the application , but there is only one instance of the Mongo client as seen in the above code.The singleton is just a classic singleton without taking consideration of double checked locking ( presuming that wont be the case)

Comment: @RobertMoskal: I have added details , any pointers why this happens will really help.

Comment: It does make sense that something like a BufferPool would grow with increased use.  Is the growth unbounded?  Does it get bigger and bigger?  Or does it grow to a point and then stay more or less constant?

Comment: @RobertMoskal: yes the memory consumption does not shrink.The more the transaction run with a find call which returns huge JSON.

Comment: I'm not asking if it shrinks. It may well be that the buffer will keep allocating more memory up until a certain point and then stops.  I'm asking if it keeps on growing forever.

Comment: @RobertMoskal:Yes it keeps on growing.

Comment: Hello, Amz. Have you solved the problem? I am facing the same situation as yours.

Comment: This question might be related to Eclipse Memory Analyser pointing to this PowerOfTwoBufferPool. And that simply holds a reference down the object graph to the classloader.

Comment: I am also seeing excessive heap consumption for `PowerOfTwoBufferPool` It is consuming 20% (48.1 mb) of heap memory on 1 instance.  The `MongoClient` is created as a spring managed singleton bean, in a spring boot app.  We run multiple instances of this process.  Heap dump analysis on two of them revealed the same issue.

Comment: Actually it is not a memory leak.  Just a buffer pool to reduce performance hit of garbage collection.  The condition is explained here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/Dj6dV7j_2MQ/4h3gtJkLBgAJ

Comment: I don't actually see a question in there anywhere.  I assume you're asking why the memory is being eaten up, and want to know how to prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

The [PowerOfTwoBufferPool](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/internal/connection/PowerOfTwoBufferPool.java) is actually a is a cache, so this may look like a memory leak at the first look.

A [mongodb-user group reply](https://groups.google.com/g/mongodb-user/c/Dj6dV7j_2MQ/m/4h3gtJkLBgAJ) has details:

> ... this
> behaviour is expected since `PowerOfTwoBufferPool` is a cache. Hence it
> may look like a leak.
>
> In short, the `PowerOfTwoBufferPool` holds a number of pools of
> ByteBuffer instances, each pool containing a set of equal-sized
> buffers. The smallest size is 1K, and the largest is 16MB,
> incrementing in power of two sizes from 1K to 16MB. The size of each
> pool of equal-sized buffers is not limited, and is determined by
> application usage. Once a buffer is cached in a pool, it remains
> pooled (or in-use) until the MongoClient is closed. As a result, it’s
> totally expected that during introspection of JVM state, the contents
> of the pools would show as a leak suspect, just as any cache would.
>
> The `PowerOfTwoBufferPool` exists in order to reduce GC load. It’s
> fairly well known that modern garbage collectors in the JVM treat
> large allocations differently from smaller ones, so if an application
> were to not do any pooling of large objects (like these buffers) it
> will have the effect of increasing GC load, because the garbage
> collector has to do more work collecting these large objects than it
> does smaller ones. The cost of this is that the driver holds on to
> memory that could be used by other parts of the application. In
> particular, it holds on to enough memory to handle the largest peak
> load seen so far by the application.

Answer (score 0):

Add a PreDestroy method where you close your client:

```
@PreDestroy
public void preDestroy() {
    try {
       if (mongoClient != null ) {
          mongoClient.close();
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error closing mongo connection : ",
                e.getCause());
    }
}
```

Of course mongoClient must be accessible to the preDestroy() method

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB driver shouldn't be part of a pool as it is unnecessary. Instead when I'm running unit tests and I don't want multiple MongoClients I use a static method. In Kotlin it looks like this:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.*
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecProvider

object MfeDatabase {
    init {
        println("SINGLETON CREATED")
    }
   const val DATABASE =""



     val client: MongoClient = MongoClients.create()
    private val pojoCodecRegistry: CodecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
        MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
        CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build())
    )
    private val db: MongoDatabase =
        client.getDatabase(DATABASE).withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry)


    @JvmStatic
    fun getDatabase(): MongoDatabase {
        return db
    }
}
```